# bash While loop not processing file contents

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have this list of shell scripts delimited by a pipe:

```
casper_one.sh|casper_two.sh|casper_three.sh|casper_four.sh|casper_five.sh
```

and what I want to do is print a absolute path in front of each scriptname:

```
/home/casper/scripts/casper_one.sh
/home/casper/scripts/casper_two.sh
/home/casper/scripts/casper_three.sh
/home/casper/scripts/casper_four.sh
/home/casper/scripts/casper_five.sh
```

I tried this, but (as you can see) it doesn't work:

```
while IFS="|" read -r line ; do
  start="/home/casper/scripts/"
  echo "$start$line"
done < casper_one.sh|casper_two.sh|casper_three.sh|casper_four.sh|casper_five.sh

-bash: casper_one.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: casper_two.sh: command not found
-bash: casper_four.sh: command not found
-bash: casper_three.sh: command not found
-bash: casper_five.sh: command not found
```

When I put the scripts names into a file and then cast it into the loop the shell throws a `File name too long` error:

```
while IFS="|" read -r line ; do
  start="/home/casper/scripts/"
  echo "$start$line"
done < $(cat /tmp/casper.txt) 
File name too long
```

Comment: Do you understand what the `< foo` notation does?

Comment: `< $(cat /tmp/casper.txt)` means read the file `/tmp/casper.txt` and use its contents as the name of a file from which to read input. You want `< /tmp/casper.txt`.

Comment: Rule of thumb:  `cat` is not often required in scripts.  If you are using it then there is probably a better way - not always, but usually.

Answer (score 0):

I won't repeat the comments about your notation, here is a couple of solutions, there are many others.

I moved `start` outside the loop, since it does not change (why set it on each iteration?).

```
start="/home/casper/scripts/"
line='casper_one.sh|casper_two.sh|casper_three.sh|casper_four.sh|casper_five.sh'

oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS="|"
for name in $line
do
  echo "$start$name"
done
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

This uses a file and an array:

```
start="/home/casper/scripts/"
IFS="|" read -a names < /tmp/casper.txt

for name in "${names[@]}"
do
  echo "$start$name"
done
```

The `read -a` reads into an array, splitting by the characters in IFS.  In this case the array is called `names`.

The `"${names[@]}"` notation gives a list of all the elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice one-liner:

```
find /home/casper/scripts/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'casper_*.sh'
```

This would output the following absolute paths:

```
/home/casper/scripts/casper_five.sh
/home/casper/scripts/casper_four.sh
/home/casper/scripts/casper_one.sh
/home/casper/scripts/casper_three.sh
/home/casper/scripts/casper_two.sh
```

This limits the recursive search to only that directory (in case you have any casper .sh files in any sub-directories). If you want to search sub-directories, remove the `-maxdepth 1` part.

You can put the output of this command into a variable like this:

```
variable="$(find /home/casper/scripts/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'casper_*.sh')"
```

Or you could export it to a temporary file like this:

```
find /home/casper/scripts/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'casper_*.sh' > /tmp/casper_output.tmp
```

Answer (score -1):

Evening, you can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
IFS="|"
path="some/path/prefix"

scripts="casper_one.sh|casper_two.sh|casper_three.sh|casper_four.sh|casper_five.sh"

for script in $scripts
do
    echo $path/$script
done
```

The for loop is easy to use in this context since it automatically iterates through the values, separated by the value of IFS.  This looks quite like the foreach loop in Python, PHP, and others.

If you want to do it via a file:

casper.txt:

> casper_one.sh|casper_two.sh|casper_three.sh|casper_four.sh|casper_five.sh

Then the script becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
IFS="|"
path="some/path/prefix"

for script in $(cat casper.txt)
do
    echo $path/$script
done
```